# How to make dropdown to be closed only on click-outside?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have multi-select dropdown, problem is cus when user select one item - dropdown is closed.

How to make that dropdown is closed only on outside click?

Dropdown is made by html ul > li:

```
// Here we loop trough list of filters and render options as <li> tags
 <ul name="filters" className="dropdown">
    {subFilters.map((filter, i) => (
      <li
        defaultChecked={filter.name}
        onClick={() => handleSelect(filter)}
        className={`option`}>
        <span>{filter.name}</span>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Css part - Classes used are:

- `dropdown` for  tag
- `option` for

```
.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 11rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #dee1e5;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.option {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  margin-left: 2.6rem;
}
```

This is how that dropdown looks: 
[image: s]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1403615/7203351
please refer this with clear understanding. Don't forget to bind and unbind the clicks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: Buddy this is not jquery.

Comment: maybe [this post from react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#mouse-and-pointer-events) can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this by `onBlur` event.

Suppose you have snippet like this :
`<div class="dropdown" onBlur={() => this.handleBlur('myModal')}>Some content</div>`

Now `this.handleBlur`

```
handleBlur = modalName => {
    this.setState({ [modalName]: false });
};
```

Comment: Didn't help, this handleBlur method what should do? change the state of openedDropdown to false? 
Not sure to undrestand you function.

Comment: Suppose modal would have a state which is boolean. So on `true` condition it will be opened and on `false` condition it will be closed.

Comment: Eg. Assign state's property to modal's toggle value. Then you have to only update that state's property to open or close modal